# How to get more details about the linux process using process Id?

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, grep, kill

I want to get more details about the processes running on the ubuntu system.

e.g. I want to kill one **java** process, but there are multiple java processes are running on my machine, so How can I identify correct one which I want?

I tried **ps -ae | grep java** which gives me all the java processes which are running, which contains tomcat, eclipse, and the one which I want to kill, but I do not understand which process to be killed?

Is there any way available to get the more details about specific process i.e. process name, its start time etc.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `ps` utility you can use e.g. `ps auxwww` to get a lot of detail, or you may use the `jps` utility to list the java processes running, eg.:

```
localhost:~# jps -v
2734 Bootstrap -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat-6/....
2933 Launcher -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=3600 -DbundleBasedir=....
10255 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26 -Xms8m
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

I usually use

`ps -ax|grep somethingIKnowAboutTCPOrTheArguments`

Normally the processes are launched in different directories or have a different starting-arguement. I use this to select on of my tomcats/java/....-process